# OpenGL: App crashes on glGetUniformLocation (but only if not installed through XCode)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, shader

to explain the situation: my OpenGL View Controller works fine when I install it via XCode (debugging mode so to speak) but crashes when installed through In House Distribution (HockeyApp is used for that).

Everything works fine without any error via XCode but breaks on line 61:
https://gist.github.com/jonasbark/561e7e66671b041f0107

```
uniforms[UNIFORM_MVP_MATRIX] = glGetUniformLocation(program, "mvp_matrix");
```

I really have no idea why. I even tried to hard code the shader files as NSString but no luck. It makes no sense to me why it wouldn't work using In House Distribution...

This is the exception reason:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
```

The uniforms field variable is introduced like this:

```
enum {
    UNIFORM_MVP_MATRIX,
    UNIFORM_TEXTURE,
    NUM_UNIFORMS
};
GLint uniforms[NUM_UNIFORMS];
```

And just in case anyone would want to see the source code: It's based on http://www.endodigital.com/opengl-es-2-0-on-the-iphone/ --> EDCubeDemo_AppendixA.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... finally solved this. 
Replaced `GLint uniforms[NUM_UNIFORMS];` with `GLint uniforms[2];` and it worked. No idea why it would fail on Release versions, must be some kind of compiler optimizations...